# Swift UI Convert UIView to View: Return type of property 'body' requires that 'UIView' conform to 'View'

Tags: swift

I have a simple View in Swift:

```
import SwiftUI

import UIKit
import React

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func loadView() {
        loadReactNativeView()
    }

    func loadReactNativeView() {
        let jsCodeLocation = URL(string: "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios")!
        
        let rootView = RCTRootView(
            bundleURL: jsCodeLocation,
            moduleName: "YourApp",
            initialProperties: nil,
            launchOptions: nil
        )
        self.view = rootView
    }
    
}


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ViewController().view
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

But the compiler complains: `Return type of property 'body' requires that 'UIView' conform to 'View'`

Can someone help me understand what am I doing wrong? I need to use UIViewController to present the View.

Here's my main implementation as given by Swift boilerplate:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct content_iosApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use `UIView` in a `SwiftUI View`. In order to use your ViewController in `SwiftUI` you need to wrap it in a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` like so:

```
struct SomeView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController {
        let viewController = ViewController()
        //additional setup
        return viewController
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
        //update Content
    }
}
```

And your ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SomeView()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make ur UIView -> UIViewRepresentable, I don't think u need a controller for your purpose.