# What is the best way open UIKit ViewController from SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I am not getting the proper solution, How to open UIKit ViewController(With Navigation Controller) from SwiftUI Button clicked.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by using the `UIViewControllerRepresentable` protocol which is used to manage your UIKit `ViewController` in the `SwiftUI`.

Here is the code to show your `ViewController` from SwiftUI View interface.

SwiftUI View

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var isOpenView = false

    var body: some View {
    
        NavigationView {

            VStack {

                //show your view controller
                NavigationLink(destination: TestControllerView(), isActive: $isOpenView) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            
                Button(action: {
                    self.isOpenView = true
                }){
                    Text("Tap Me")
                }                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now wrap your ViewController into `UIViewControllerRepresentable`

```
struct TestControllerView : UIViewControllerRepresentable {

     func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
    
     }

     func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {

        guard let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: "TestViewController") as? TestViewController else {
            fatalError("ViewController not implemented in storyboard")
        }
    
        return viewController
     }
}
```

Here is your ViewController.Swift File code

```
import UIKit

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     }

     @IBAction func btnBackClicked(_ sender : UIButton) {
         self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, wrap your `UIViewController` in a `UIViewControllerRepresantable` [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72444186/13278922).

Then present that `View` using `.fullScreenCover`